# ¿Rediseñar un programa para que datos de entrada se pidan al inicio, antes de entrar al menú principal, usando parámetros?

Tags: c++, parametros

Soy un programador principiante de C ++.

La tarea actual que tengo según las instrucciones de mi maestro es:

"Rediseñe el siguiente programa que creaste la semana pasada en C ++ que tendrá los datos de entrada que se solicitarán al principio, antes de ingresar al menú principal, esto para usar parámetros en cada una de las funciones rediseñadas.
La tarea para la cual hice el programa en C++ es la siguiente y me fue bien.  Solo que ahora se me pide que haga un programa en donde primero se ingresen los datos de entrada y que luego salga el menu.

Problema de la semana pasada ya resuelta la cual ahora se debe rediseñar:

Cree un programa para calcular las áreas y los perímetros de algunas figuras geométricas.

Se programará un menú principal que contiene las siguientes opciones:

Areas

Perímetros

Salida

En la primera opción, tendrá un submenú con las opciones: 1. Cuadrado 2. Trapecio 3. Esfera 4. Salir

En la segunda opción, tendrá un submenú con las opciones: 1. Rectángulo 2. Triángulo 3. Círculo 4. Salir

Realice el cálculo para cada área y perímetro en una función, cada función le pedirá al usuario los datos de entrada necesarios para calcular las áreas o perímetros correspondientes.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void Areas()
{
    cout << "Elija una opcion";
}
void Perimetros()
{
    cout << "Elija una opcion";
}     
int main()
{
  int input; 
  cout<<"1. Area de Cuadrilatero, Trapecio o Esfera\n";
  cout<<"2. Perimetro de Rectangulo, Triangulo o Circulo\n";
  cout<<"3. Salir\n";
  cout<<"Elija una opcion: ";
  cin>> input;
  switch ( input ) 
{
  case 1:
  int input; 
  cout<<"1. Area de Cuadrilatero\n";
  {
   int square_area, square_side;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del lado: ";
   cin >> square_side;
   square_area = square_side * square_side;
   cout << "Area del Cuadrilatero es: " << square_area << endl;   
} 
  cout<<"2. Area de Trapecio\n";  
  { 
 int b1,b2,h,a;
 cout<<"Ingrese la longitud de la base menor del Trapecio :";
 cin>>b1;
 cout<<"Ingrese la longitud de la base mayor del Trapecio :";
 cin>>b2;
 cout<<"Ingrese la altura del Trapecio :";
 cin>>h;
 a=((b1+b2)*h)/2;
 cout<<"El Area del Trapecio es: "<<a << endl;
}   
  cout<<"3. Area de Esfera\n"; 
  {
   int radio, sphere_area;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del Radio: ";
   cin >> radio;
   sphere_area = radio * radio*3.1416;
   cout << "Area de la Esfera es: " << sphere_area << endl;
} 
  cout<<"Desea salir de la aplicacion(s/n)?"<<"\n";
int opcion;
cin>>opcion;
if (opcion=='s' || opcion=='s')
return 0;
if (opcion =='n' || opcion=='n')
cout<<"continuemos con..."<<"\n";
system ("pause");
  case 2: 
  cout<<"1. Perimetro de Triangulo\n";
  {
   int x, y, z, p;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del lado x: ";
   cin >> x;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del lado y: ";
   cin >> y;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del lado z: ";
   cin >> z;
   p = x+y+z;
   cout << "Perimetro de Triangulo es: " << p << endl;  
} 
  cout<<"2. Perimetro de Rectangulo\n";  
  { 
 int v,alt,p;
 cout<<"Ingrese la longitud de la base del Rectangulo :";
 cin>>v;
 cout<<"Ingrese la altura del Rectangulo :";
 cin>>alt;
 p=v+v+alt+alt;
 cout<<"El perimetro del Rectangulo es: "<<p << endl;
}   
  cout<<"3. Perimetro de Circulo\n"; 
  {
   int radio, circle_perimeter;
   cout << "Ingrese la longitud del Radio: ";
   cin >> radio;
   circle_perimeter = radio * radio*3.1416;
   cout << "Perimetro del Circulo es: " << circle_perimeter << endl;
} 
  cout<<"Desea salir de la aplicacion(s/n)?"<<"\n";
cin>>opcion;
if (opcion=='s' || opcion=='s')
return 0;
if (opcion =='n' || opcion=='n')
cout<<"continuemos con..."<<"\n";
system ("pause");
  case 3:            
    cout<<"Desea salir de la aplicacion(s/n)?"<<"\n";
cin>>opcion;
if (opcion=='s' || opcion=='s')
return 0;
if (opcion =='n' || opcion=='n')
cout<<"continuemos con..."<<"\n";
system ("pause");    
    {
}
  default:            
    cout<<"";
  }
  cin.get();
}
```

Pero ahora mi maestro quiere que rediseñe el programa anterior para que se solicite la entrada de datos (por ejemplo, el radio, la longitud de los lados de un triángulo, rectángulo, trapecio, etc.) desde un principio. Luego aparecerá el menú principal dando a elegir al usuario qué desea calcular con los datos que fueron ingresados ​​al principio.
 
Personalmente considero que un programa debe mostrar el menú al principio y no al revés solicitando la entrada de datos desde el principio.

Answer (score 0):

> […] rediseñe el programa anterior para que se solicite la entrada de datos (por ejemplo, el radio, la longitud de los lados de un triángulo, rectángulo, trapecio, etc.) desde un principio.

Para empezar, debes cambiar la firma de la función `main` para que reciba parámetros:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // …
    return 0;
}
```

El valor de `argc` indica cuántos parámetros has recibido, ten en cuenta que **siempre** se recibe como mínimo uno, que será la ruta desde la que se ha llamado el programa. En `argv` tendrás (como texto) los parámetros recibidos, si tu programa se llama `p.exe` y lo llamas así:

```
p 1 2 3 responda otra vez
```

El valor de `argc` será `7` y `argv[0]` contendrá `"X:\ruta\p.exe"`, `argv[1]` contendrá `"1"`, `argv[2]` contendrá `"2"`, …

Dado que cada opción requiere una cantidad de parámetros distinta, al escoger cada opción deberás comprobar que te han pasado suficientes parámetros mirando el valor de `argc`, después deberás transformar los valores de `argv` de texto a número.

Comment: int main(int argc, char **argv)                 y si ahí está la clave, gracias, analizaré esa estructura profundamente.

Comment: No tengo ni la más remota idea de qué es lo que intentas transmitir con los comentarios que has añadido a la respuesta.